# AngularJS ui-router: URL with params and without params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

i am currently working on a SPA for managing user identities in. I now have a problem defining URLs for states in angular ui-router.

Here is what i figured out so far:

```
    .state('identity', {
        url: '/identity/:serialNumber',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/Identity/identity.html',
        controller: 'identityController'
    })
    .state('addidentity', {
        url: '/identity/add',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/Identity/identityAdd.html',
        controller: 'identityController'
    });
```

The first state ("identity") gets passed the URL paramter "serialNumber". This works fine and i can access the param within the "identityController".

What i want to achieve with the second state ("addidentity") is, that for the special case of accessing "/identity/add" i want to redirect to a different template (and maybe using a different controller in the future).

However, this does not work. Only the first state does. The second is ignored. From what i understand, the problem is that even though i access "/identity/add", this URL technically still complies with the first state. In this case, the state param "serialNumber" will simply set to "add".

I think i have a problem understanding how exactly ui-router works. 
Is there a way in ui-router to handle those two URLs differently?

Maybe there is something fundamentally wrong in the way i thought about this. Any help would be appreciated :)

Regards,

Timo

Comment: Can you provide more files? Especially the html files and controller

Comment: There is nothing in the controller except  `console.log($stateParams.serialNumber);`. I havent started implementing more functionality yet.

Comment: By changing mapping it will work like '/identity/find/:serialNumber'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate an url with a regex :
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters

If, for example your serial number is an integer, the following will make the url match only for integers :

```
.state('identity', {
    url: '/identity/{serialNumber:[0-9]{1,8}}',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/Identity/identity.html',
    controller: 'identityController'
})
.state('addidentity', {
    url: '/identity/add',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/Identity/identityAdd.html',
    controller: 'identityController'
});
```

Comment: Thats it! Thank you. 
Since serialNumber is always an integer value, this works perfectly.